# How to disable MongoDB aggregation timeout

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I want to run aggregation on my large data sets. (It's about 361K documents) and Insert them to another collection.
I getting this error:

[image: Mongo Compass]

I tried to increase `Max Time` but it has maximum and it's not enough for my data sets. I found https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/ but it seems `noCursorTimeout` only apply on `find` not aggregation.

please tell me how I can disable cursor timeout or another solution to do this.

Comment: It's possible but complicated. Let me know if you want an explanation as to why

Comment: Yes, please tell me why

Comment: sorry for my delayed response

Answer (score 0):

I am no MongoDB expert but will interpret what I know.

MongoDB Aggregation Cursors don't have a mechanism to adjust `Batch Size` or set `Cursor Timeouts`.

Therefore there is no direct way to alter this and the timeout of an aggregation query solely depends on the `cursorTimeoutMillis` parameter of the `MongoDB or` mongos` instance. Its default timeout value is 10 minutes.

Your only option is to change this value by the below command.

```
use admin 
db.runCommand({setParameter:1, cursorTimeoutMillis: 1800000})
```

However, I strongly advise you against using this command. That's because it's a safety mechanism built into MongoDB. It automatically deletes queries that are running idle for more than 10 minutes, so that there is a lesser load in the MongoDB server. If you change this parameter (say to 30 minutes), MongoDB will allow idle queries to be running in the background for those 30 minutes, which will not only make all the new queries slower to execute, but also increase load and memory on the MongoDB side.

You have a couple of workarounds. Reduct the amount of documents if working on MongoDB Compass or copy and run the commands on Mongo Shell (I had success so far with this method).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Mongodb 5 there is a new feature called maxTimeMS.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Quote from documentation:

```
Optional. Specifies a time limit in milliseconds for processing operations on a cursor. If you do not specify a value for maxTimeMS, operations will not time out. A value of 0 explicitly specifies the default unbounded behavior.
```